# iOS: Making a UIImage stay put on top in Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

The image bellow shows my problem - I want  a ripped paper effect as seen here but when I 
scroll up or down, as you see on the image the ripped paper moves as well - I want it to at least keep it´s position when user scrolls up. How do I archive this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: Mrunal: I tried to move the image behind the table view in Interface builder, is it maybe possible if I place a View and the image in that view behind the tableview?

Comment: How did you set ripped paper image background, Is it background of uitableview or the view controller?

Comment: Idinu: see updated post with image. If i try to move the image to the view controller it just dissapears

Comment: First keep image outside tableview (above position in list). Then change uitableview background color to clear color.

Comment: Mrunal: I cannot get the image above the TableView in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the navigation bar's [`shadowImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/shadowImage) to set the ripped paper as well as the shadow. You'll have to set the bar's background image too for it to work. You may have to change the offset of the table view too if the image is tall.

Comment: Works perfectly but do you know how I can remove the shadow image from the navigation bar when entering another part of the UI were i do not want it?

Comment: Never mind! just to set in to nil.     UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
    bar.shadowImage = nil;

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be add image view followed by tableview to the view controller and set image to the image view. tableview background view should be set to nil and background color should be set to clear color.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    backgroundImageView.image = "Your image";
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:"Desired frame"];
    tableview.backgroundView = nil;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview: tableView]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `backgroundView` property to achieve the affect you want. Place this in viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableViewBackground.png"]];
```